# Ansible won't copy file. Gives permission denied

Tags: ansible

Its a super simple task. It copies a file on the local machine from one directory to another. I keep getting permission denied.  I dropped the variables block from the snippet below. I have tested using the command line, and am able to cp and mv the file between these two directories. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
- name: Packing up $HOME and moving to FileExpress
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: False
  tasks:
    - name: Copy package
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: "/tmp/{{ package }}"
        dest: "{{ fedir }}/{{ package }}"
        mode: 0644
        remote_src: True
```

The error I am receiving is below. Anything that is from a variable has been surrounded with {{}}

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "failed to copy: /tmp/{{package}} to /{{fedir}}", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.copy_payload_8zc9gcnj/ansible_ansible.legacy.copy_payload.zip/ansible/modules/copy.py\", line 670, in main\n  File \"/home/{{user}}/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/tempfile.py\", line 332, in mkstemp\n    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)\n  File \"/home/{{user}}/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/tempfile.py\", line 251, in _mkstemp_inner\n    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)\nPermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: b'/{{fedir}}/tmp8b2t3qrz'\n"}
```

Comment: You think that you are `able to cp and mv the file between these two directories`. Ansible is telling you `permission denied`. Either you are completely wrong or ansible is using a different user than the one you tested with.

Comment: I have tested pretty thoroughly the copy/move operations. I have also run a task to kick out the response for "whoami" in the debug info to check the user.  That is why I am stumped.

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/1522927/ansible-copy-module-become-permission-denied

Answer (score 1):

After testing, I still don't know why it won't work, but the **copy** module won't work. Neither did using the **command** module to run a script that did the copy. I tried to use the **shell** module to run the script, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try `become: True` to give `sudo` privileges to the command. Ansible does not use the same user you are using when you test from the command line.  It's been a while since I touched Ansible and his may not be the best way to do this, but I do remember solving a lot of issues with `become: True` in a past life.